# How to Sync Cronjob with the files its running which takes more than 5 mins to complete but i have Cronjob set for every 3 mins

Tags: shell, unix, cron

I am facing a problem with the scripts which i am using in my code, my cronjob runs every 5 mins but the scripts which it is running some time takes more time and i want my cronjob to wait for those files to finish its processing and then execute in the earliest interval is it possible?

Please see below example. Kindly propose me a solution. TIA.

I am running a cronjob for e.g.:

```
*/5 * * * * /home/Sti/New_Int/fetch_My_Data.sh
```

This job is invoking below scripts and few details about what each script is doing

1. fetch_Some_Data.sh --> This script is just moving few files from one location to another so that the only required files can be processed.
2. tran.sh --> This script opens a for loop and for each file it will open a DB connection by invoking PostP.sh script and for processing it has a sleep time of 60 seconds.
3. PostP.sh --> This is a script which creates a DB connection and terminates it for each file which is being processed in point 2.

So can you provide me a solution so that if the files are not processed in point 2 the cronjob won't run till then

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a temporary file in such cases to indicate a running instance, and till that file exists all other instances simply exit or Error.
Add this logic to your shell script before doing anything else:
if exists file
then
exit
end if
else
touch empty file
end else

Comment: Other option is instead of cron you create a background process in the parent code and then exit. you can add wait for 5mins before you call and exit as well.